# Casting an ArraySeq as an IFn

Tags: clojure, evaluation

Elementary question here.. I am a little confused.

```
(((fn [_ & y] y) 'blah +) 3 4)
```

will result in the error:

> "java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn"

I was rather hoping for it to be evaluated to:

```
(+ 3 4)
```

which equals 7.

I see that

```
((fn [_ & y] y) 'blah +)
```

evaluates to

```
(#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@7cd07b83>)
```

which is an ArraySeq, not an IFn; so I understand the error- however I am not sure why it doesn't just evaluate to a + instead.

Answer (score 3):

`&` puts all excess arguments in a collection. This can be destructured to access its first element:

```
user> (((fn [_ & [y & _]] y) 'blah +) 3 4)
7
```

or, equivalently,

```
user> (((fn [_ & ys] (first ys)) 'blah +) 3 4)
7
```

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand `&` in function argument destruction collects all remaining arguments to a seq, even if there is only one there.

```
user=> ((fn [_ & y] y) 'blah +)
(#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@205074de>)
user=> ((fn [_ y] y) 'blah +)
#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@205074de>
```